# DirectShow with capture card blurry pixels

Tags: c#, directshow, video-capture

I'm programming a directshow application with streaming card. First I installed the drivers and tried their streaming software, everything works perfect and its pixel perfect. 
Then make C# code for capturing still images through directshow, pretty much exact copy of  DxWebCam example, to be found here in official net library:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/

I also tried more modern approach of using pins and smartee, however I was not able to make it work. 
The issue is, the images captured with directshow are just a bit off, like it is using some sort of compression. To demonstrate my issue, here is the original pixel perfect image: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE9tp.png]
and here is the directshow captured image, with some sort of horizontal pixel mashup:  [image: imgur.com/MyZFaLC.png] (need to zoom in to see the wrong pixels)

I've tried setting massive bitrate as well as playing with video formats etc. 
However I'm just not able to stream pixel perfect in directshow, yet on the same computer with native manufacturer application it works perfectly.

I'm lost as in how to continue or how to try to debug this. Any help appreciated

Comment: The size of the two images are different (29x29 for the original and 16x16 for the captured), Is this really happening or is it a error in posting your question, if it is happening down-scaling can induce blurriness.

Comment: Hi, I only messed up the source of the image, its logo from google spreadsheets, and one is taken from the tab in chrome and one is taken directly from sheet. They are different size, however I just checked it, and the problem still stands. I don't do any downscaling in my directshow code, its all full hd. It just seems like it produces some color downsampling, however the card is capable of profucing RGB 4:4:4 as it does in its native app. My  app seems like its producing 4:2:2. I'm new to Directshow, however I don't think im using any filters for downscaling, I just mostly copied the sample.